# Return 1 if multiple columns are true, return 0 if only one column is true

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like the following:

| id | bucket_1 | bucket_2 | bucket_3 | bucket_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7689 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3456 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4567 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 5677 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4567 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

What I need to do is to write SQK code that looks at bucket 1 to 4 and if more than one of these columns have a value of 1, then mark it as 1 or true, and otherwise mark it as 0 or false.
Here is the table that I am trying to make:

| id | bucket_1 | bucket_2 | bucket_3 | bucket_4 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7689 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3456 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4567 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5677 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4567 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Could you help how this can be achieved? I am not sure how it can be done with the case clause.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when bucket_1 + bucket_2 + bucket_3 + bucket_4 > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as result
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly do:

```
select t.*, 
          +(bucket_1 + bucket_2 + bucket_3 + bucket_4 > 1) result 
from t
```